# Encode array of image objects to movie file

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, image, movie

I have a array that is full of image objects, I need to be able to encode that array into a movie project. I have a Java server that I will use if needed, but I would prefer only having this client-side with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about encoding into a standard format like H.264 or Web.M, then you should use your Java server and the bindings to FFmpeg or whatever your preferred video library is. Many JavaScript clients are not fast enough to encode video, and pre-existing software does not exist for this task. I'd think that Internet Explorer would be problematic in particular, because of how low it's interpreted JS engine is compared to the JIT compilers in projects like Gecko or Webkit.

Answer (score 0):

@Just Jake is right: FFMPEG is very strong tool that allows to implement this task. But you have a pure java solution as weell. To implement it you need JMF - java media framework.